# How to concatenate a string with SpEL in SpringXD Stream Definition

Tags: spring-integration, spring-el, spring-xd

I'm trying to create a stream definition that uses two payload fields joined together to create a concatenated string.

```
stream create --name blah --definition "http | gemfire-json-server --keyExpression=payload.getField('deviceId') + payload.getField('timestamp')" --deploy`
```

The concatenation piece in the `keyExpression` is incorrect, what should it be to get it to work inline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer to you is based on the fact that String has `concat()` method. So, you code may look like:

```
--keyExpression=payload.getField('deviceId').concat(payload.getField('timestamp'))
```

From other side, here you are a quote from XD Reference Manual:

> It is only necessary to quote parameter values if they contain spaces or the | character. Here the transform processor module is being passed a SpEL expression that will be applied to any data it encounters:

```
      transform --expression='new StringBuilder(payload).reverse()'
```

And find this [chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#dsl-quotes-escaping), please, for more information about quotes.